# Is there a way to open and view the storyboard in two different windows on Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1  I would like to have the same storyboard open in two side-by-side windows.  I tried using the Assistant Editor to manually open the same storyboard and that works fine but when I click on one side or the other the storyboard in the other window disappears.

The reason I'm trying to do this is I want to replicate parts of the storyboard to another part and it's annoying to keep navigating all over the place and trying to remember what it looked like.

Answer (score 0):

No. Storyboard is a XML file, that save changes not as often as to work with it from two screens. It can lead to mistakes. However you can temporary copy UIViewControllers and place them wherever you need, replicate parts and delete them.

Comment: I don't see how it being an XML file would make a difference.  XML is just text, the same as a Swift file and there is no problem having two of those open at the same time.  Also, anytime I copy anything in a storyboard it always ruins all of the constraints making it often easier to just reconstruct things, hence why I would like two storyboards.